# Django - is it possible to avoid/minimize use of migrations?

Tags: python, django, database-migration, ddl

This is a general question.  I'll give a sample of what I am concerned about, but the general idea I am after is:  can I bypass migrations to manage the schema for the models?  Now, I know there are lots of good reasons people *like* migrations, but I am proficient with DDL SQL and looking after schema changes and am finding that, **for my use cases**, I spend way more time working around migrations than I do benefiting from them.  I don't use fixtures for example and I don't need very dynamic migration capability a la Chef/Puppet, at least not until I am in production.

In fact, I find the lack of transparency around migration DDL quite scary.

**This is just a sample issue I am dealing with:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    rdbname = RDBNAME
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rolecount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    usercount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-rolecount", "name"]
```

I have just added this index, it shows up in migrations, 
but it doesn't get created

```
        unique_together = ("rdbname", "name")
```

This is the output:

```
Running migrations:
   No migrations to apply.
```

But this is NOT a request to help me troubleshoot my migration.  I can probably drop the affected tables get migrations to recreate them.  Or add the index by hand.  I just generally don't want to use **manage.py migrate** and I wonder if there are ways to benefit from Models but look after your db the old fashioned, manual way.

One possible approach would be to use makemigrations in a "from-scratch/dry-run/sql output" mode to create a sql script.  With all drop/create tables and indices, as if the database was empty.  If you compare that to your previous from-scratch, you would see whatever was changed and you could create a script to say just add a column.  Or my index in my case.

And you would execute that in your favorite sql utility, psql (Postgres) in my case.

Can I not get a long set of explanations why migrations are the cat's pajamas?  I am aware of those already.  But I would be happy to hear from people who have tried that there is no way out, that's a useful data point for me. I'll just have to bite the bullet as well.

Just wondering if anyone else has managed to work around them somewhat.

Comment: Your output seems wrong --- there definitely should be a migration created for that, but you don't show that you create one, only that you run them. If nothing happens, that is a bug, but it seems you didn't create one.

Comment: Agree.  But that's really not the point.  My question is about how to avoid/minimize dealing with them because I find them unpredictable and they don't fit my workflow.

Comment: Still I find it hard to understand what kind of answer you're looking for. There is of course the option of not using them at all and doing everything by hand, but you want to "work around them somewhat", but without saying what about them it is you want to work around exactly.

Comment: Like I said, obtain a DDL SQL for the full module, as if the db was empty.  I can take it from there.  If I do everything by hand, that doesn't tell me that my DDL meets the expectations of what the Models think should be in the database.  If I start with a full drop/create set of commands, then my job is just to tweak that DDL to take into account the current state of my db.  This is something I do know how to do.

Comment: python manage.py sql?

Comment: that does look more promising.  thanks.  Now it's complaining that I have migrations, grrr, but once I get that sorted out I'll take another look at manage.py sql.

Comment: You can also get the sql it would run for a migration with `sqlmigrate <applabel> <migrationname>`, then edit it to do what you want exactly and fake the migration (or make it empty, or call your sql from inside it, or whatever).

Comment: ok, that is also useful, but in my current issue, the problem is that it doesn't seem to think a migration is necessary for my unique index.  I suspect moving from Django 1.6/South to 1.7/new migration mechanism is somewhat related to this mess, but I have generally found migrations to be brittle and flakey.  Python and Django generally allow you to work as you wish (*and sometimes that means I do stupid things, I admit*), but migrations seem very coupled into Django.

Comment: Try with `unique_together = (("rdbname", "name"), )`? It's supposed to be a tuple of tuples, and a single tuple works as a convenience, but didn't for a while with the new migrations ( see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21236 )

Comment: Oh wait, in your current code, `rdbname` doesn't appear to be a field on the model!? Not sure how that would work at all.